# String Splitting with multiple delimiters java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am splitting below string with multiple delimiters. 
Delimiters are:

```
, . @ ? ! _ ' and white space etc.
```

Below is my code:

```
String[] tokens = s.split("[!|?|,|.|_|'|@ |\\s]");
```

For input:

> He is a very very good boy, isn't he?

Expected output after split is: 10 tokens

> He
>   is
>   a
>   very
>   very
>   good
>   boy
>   isn
>   t
>   he

But I am getting below ouput: 11 tokens

> He
>   is
>   a
>   very
>   very
>   good
>   boy
>
> isn
>   t
>   he

Because two delimiters whitespace and comma are adjacent, it is giving 11 tokens. How to get expected output?

Comment: first thing first..character class is OR condition for characters..so no need of using `|` in character class

Comment: Can you be more specific with your "etc." in your delimiters? What other characters would be delimiters?

Comment: You can use string tokenization too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `+` for finding the combination, if you want to avoid multiple consecutive delimiters which results in empty string

```
s.split("[,.@?!_'\\s]+")
```

**NOTE** :- As I mentioned in comment, character class itself works as `OR` condition for characters. So, there is no need of using `|` inside character class for achieving alternation, because it will match `|` literally.

Answer (score 3):

To match more than one consecutive delimiter, use the `+`:

```
s.split("[,.@?!_'\\s]+");
```

Another regex that you should consider using is:

```
s.split("[\\W_]+");
```

This will split so that any non-word character will be treated as a delimiter. This is not specified by your question, but it has the output you expect as well.

Comment: that's univerally nice!